# segfault when x86 vmread instruction is executed

Tags: x86, virtualization, xen

I am trying to implement my own vmread function that implements x86 vmread instruction for educational purpose. Why did the following give segmentation fault on xen hypervisor.

Kernel version : `4.9.0-4-amd64`
xen version : `4.8.3-pre (preserve-AD)`

vmread.h

```
int vmread(unsigned long long int, int*);
```

vmread.S

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.globl vmread
.type vmread, @function

vmread:
    vmread [rsi], rdi
    jbe __vmx_failure
    jmp __vmx_success

__vmx_failure:
    mov rax, 0x0
    ret

__vmx_success:
    mov rax, 0x1
```

testvmread.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "vmread.h"
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
        int value = 0;
        uint64_t addr = 0x00002804ULL;
        vmread(addr,    &value);
        printf("the value of GUEST_IA32_PAT is %d  \n", value);
        return 0;
    }
```

compiled with `gcc testvmread.c vmread.S -o test`

Comment: And you're running this under Linux under Xen?  What do you mean "freezes", exactly?  It locks up your whole Linux VM?  That sounds like a huge security vulnerability if a user-space process inside a guess can lock up the whole guest, or especially the whole system (hypervisor + all guests).  It's hard to believe such a major problem could be triggered with such simple code, unless it's a new bug in Linux or Xen.  (I don't use Xen, so I can't easily test.  Please add version numbers for your Xen + Linux setup.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated the question. I am sorry I mean seg fault here.

Comment: Oh.  Is there some reason you expect `vmread` to be usable in user-space?  The manuals says (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VMREAD.html) it raises `#GP(0)` if the current privilege level isn't 0.  (i.e. it requires ring 0 aka kernel mode).

Comment: #GP(0) looks like, this is the reason for segfault. How do I make this code run as kernel module?

Comment: In addition to the other problems noted, vmread writes 8 bytes, so the second parameter to your vmread function should be a uint64_t \*, not an int \*.